# Unable to access Business Central/Decision Central even on a fresh installation of the product and displays message "Please wait Loading Application"

Tags: jbpm, redhat-bpm

I have installed the current version of jbpm.
After the installation, start and successful login Business central waits for forever and the page does not appear.

I have found the problem reported before:

https://issues.redhat.com/browse/RHBPMS-2460

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1183473

I am surprised that no solutions has been documented.

Does anybody know the solution/workaround?

Thanks for advance, Elmar

Comment: Just downloaded an installed jbpm 7.30. Same error.
Here is an excerpt of the error log from chrome dev tools:

org.kie.bc.KIEWebapp-0.js:104158 12:24:57 SEVERE [InitVotes] components failed to initialize
FJH @ org.kie.bc.KIEWebapp-0.js:104158
org.kie.bc.KIEWebapp-0.js:104158 12:24:57 SEVERE [InitVotes]    [failed] -> org.jboss.errai.enterprise.client.cdi.api.CDI
FJH @ org.kie.bc.KIEWebapp-0.js:104158
Styles.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Can you describe your server set up? What app server are you running it in?  Do you get any server side error logs or in browser only?

Comment: I am trying to run the Standalone app with OpenJDK 1.8 (redhat). Still facing loading issue

Comment: Any ideas on this ?